# 2010 version MFC code doesn't work anymore on 2013, any suggestions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

How should I change this vs2010 code to work in vs2013?

This is part of MFC application.  I have two Edit Control with CString variables m_Name, and m_Age.  There is also a print button that if clicked it shows these two information on a Message Box.

```
void CMyProgramDlg::OnBUTTON_PRINT()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    char szText[100];
    sprintf(szText, "Name: %s\n"\
                    "Age: %d",
                    m_Name, m_Age);
    MessageBox(szText, m_Name+"Message", NULL);
```

}

The problem is MessageBox() doesn't take char any more.  So I converted to CString.  But the new problem is the printed message only shows the first letter of the name and age.  So if I put in 'Jack' for the name and '40' for the age, it only shows 'J' and '4'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new project apparently compiles in Unicode mode, so `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, and all WinAPI functions accept `wchar_t` instead of `char` (or pointers to them).

More precisely: The macro `MessageBox` that expanded to `MessageBoxA` in the old project now expands to `MessageBoxW`, and where `MessageBoxA` accepted pointers to `char`, `MessageBoxW` expects pointers to `wchar_t`. This mechanism exists for all WinAPI "functions" that accept strings.

Go into the project's project properties and set "Character Set" under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General to not set or multibyte instead of Unicode, then it should behave as before. Alternatively, use `MessageBoxA` instead of `MessageBox` to invoke the ANSI version explicitly, or change the code so that it uses `TCHAR` everywhere.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx for details.

Comment: Note that if you want to use MBCS in VS2013, you need to [download the separate add-on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251007.aspx) because it's no longer included by default.

Answer (score 1):

The VS 2013 no longer supports MBCS. So you have to convert your code to UNICODE:

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
CString szText;
szText.Format(_T("Name: %s\nAge: %d"), m_Name, m_Age);
MessageBox(szText, m_Name + _T("Message"), NULL);
```